# Recursively Edit Semi-Arbitrary Nested Maps in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, recursion

I am working on creating a recursive method in Java that will be able to edit a semi-arbitrary nested `Map`. I need to be able to traverse the `Map` and then edit and/or delete any arbitrary value. This method will fit inside a larger application, and thus there are parts I do not have control over.

### Constraints

I am working within some constraints:

1. My method must edit the `Map` passed in as a parameter. Any return value is ignored by the larger application this is in.
2. Minimize memory usage. The passed in data `Map` can be large (Over 250 MB). I need to avoid creating temporary copies of it.
3. For a given key, there is a limited amount of possible values:

   - Another `Map`
   - A `List`
   - A Single Value (String, boolean, number)
4. I will need to keep track of where I am as I navigate through the `Map`.
5. Avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`s

## Illustrative Example Code

I have put together an example for this question. For this question, the example code has been simplified to just recursively traversing the `Map` and removing `List` values if `canRemove` returns `true` (Which it has been hardcoded to due so for some additional simplification). First, here is the class that contains the recursive logic that I have been working with.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

// the Modifier Interface is part of the larger application in which this Class plugs into
public class FooModifier implements Modifier
{
   private void recursiveModifier(Map<String, Object> dataMap, String path)
   {
      for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = dataMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
         Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
         if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map< ? , ? >)
         {
            // recursively call recursiveModifier on entry.getValue(),
            recursiveModifier((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), path + "." + entry.getKey());
         }
         else if (entry.getValue() instanceof List)
         {
            String listPath = path + "." + entry.getKey();
            if (canRemove(listPath))
            {
               it.remove();
            }
            else
            {
               // May change modify other types, but not for this example
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void recursiveModifier(Map<String, Object> data)
   {
      // Call private recursive function with data and empty path string
      recursiveModifier(data, "");
   }

   @Override
   public void run(Map<String, Object> data)
   {
      recursiveModifier(data);
      // Do other stuff
   }

   private boolean canRemove(String listPath)
   {
      // Would perform logic to check if given path can be removed.
      // For this example, just set to true
      return true;
   }
}
```

Here is a dummy class with a main method that can be used to execute FooModifier for illustrative purposes.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// Dummy Main that loads dummy data just for illustrative purposes. 
public class DummyMain
{
   private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
   private static final String FILE_PATH = "files/data.json";

   public static void main(String[] args)
      throws JsonParseException,
         JsonMappingException,
         IOException
   {
      // Read in JSON. Contents can be arbitrary.
      Map<String, Object> data = MAPPER.readValue(new File(FILE_PATH), Map.class);

      // Runs FooModifier with dummy data
      FooModifier modifier = new FooModifier();
      modifier.run(data);

      // Just to print output for this example
      System.out.println(MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data));
   }
}
```

Lastly, here is the dummy datafile used by the dummy main class:

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Item1": true,
    "Item2": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "Item3": {
      "Baz": {
        "BazData1": false,
        "BazData2": "BlahBlahBlah"
      },
      "BazBaz": 2
    }
  },
  "Bar": {
    "Item1": false,
    "Item2": ["x", "y", "z"],
    "Item3": {
      "Baz": {
        "BazData1": true,
        "BazData2": "Tick Tock"
      },
      "BazBaz": 4
    }
  },
  "Bonk": "Boom"
}
```

## Question

I provided what I am working with so far, but am not sure that it is the most efficient way of doing this task. I interested in seeing if there is a better way.

*What is the optimal way to do this task? Please explain why your answer is optimal.*

Comment: This looks fine to me. Is there some reason you're concerned about performance? It should run in a trivial amount of time, even for very large maps.

Comment: @teppic : Thanks for the comment. For performance, I am more concerned about memory usage than time. The application is already tight on memory, and I need to be careful. By contrast, running fast is not as big a priority.